# Can't cast library class to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-library

I added Yahoo weather library to m project. Then I tried to implement YahooWeatherInfoListener to the main fragment.

There is a problem.

Inside `AsyncTask` I can't cast `YahooWeatherInfoListener` to the fragment.

I think there is sth I'm doin wrong inside AsncTask. Please take a look:

```
import zh.wang.android.apis.yweathergetter4a.WeatherInfo;
import zh.wang.android.apis.yweathergetter4a.YahooWeather;
import zh.wang.android.apis.yweathergetter4a.YahooWeather.SEARCH_MODE;
import zh.wang.android.apis.yweathergetter4a.YahooWeatherInfoListener;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements YahooWeatherInfoListener {

public HomeFragment(){}
private TextView Temperature;
private YahooWeather mYahooWeather = YahooWeather.getInstance(5000, 5000, true);

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    Temperature = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtLabel);
    new searchByGPS().execute();
    return rootView;
}
private class searchByGPS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        mYahooWeather.setNeedDownloadIcons(true);
        mYahooWeather.setSearchMode(SEARCH_MODE.GPS);
        mYahooWeather.queryYahooWeatherByGPS(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), (YahooWeatherInfoListener) this);

        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

    }
}
@Override
public void gotWeatherInfo(WeatherInfo weatherInfo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Temperature.setText(weatherInfo.getCurrentTempC());
}
}
```

Comment: you want to use `HomeFragment.this` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        mYahooWeather.setNeedDownloadIcons(true);
        mYahooWeather.setSearchMode(SEARCH_MODE.GPS);
        mYahooWeather.queryYahooWeatherByGPS(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), (YahooWeatherInfoListener) HomeFragment.this);

        return null;
    }
```

You have to change your `this` to `HomeFragment.this` because this is directly connected to your AsyncTask.

Comment: Now got this error: "Ca't create handler inside looper that has not called looper.prepare();"

Comment: so there is a thread in a thread. As the example shows you do not have to use a asynctask this time https://github.com/zh-wang/YWeatherGetter4a/blob/master/sample_app/src/zh/wang/android/yweathergetter4a/sample/MainActivity.java

Comment: You mean I must use progress dialog without AsyncTask? Don't I get main thread exception Error (As GPS is searching for location)?

Comment: Solved! But a funny error: App comes up but after some seconds (I think after retrieving temperature) App crashes with this error: "String Resource not found ID:0*14...)" It seems can't find textview to insert temperature. But I checked textview is there and ID is correct. I even added another textview inside fragment layout.

Comment: I think this is the problem because you want to set a int as text, so Temperature.setText(14) will look for the string ressource 14, just chnage it to Temperature.setText("" + 14) and it will display 14

Comment: Check this out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int) do not set integer values as text if you want to display it

Comment: I REALLY am a dummy. I didn't notice the result is integer.

Answer (score 2):

That's because in

```
(YahooWeatherInfoListener) this
```

`this` refers to the `AsyncTask`. Instead, you need to use:

```
(YahooWeatherInfoListener) HomeFragment.this
```

The cleaner way to implement this would be:

```
private class SearchByGPSTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    private YahooWeatherInfoListener mListener;

    public SearchByGPSTask( YahooWeatherInfoListener listener ) {
        super();
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        mYahooWeather.setNeedDownloadIcons(true);
        mYahooWeather.setSearchMode(SEARCH_MODE.GPS);
        mYahooWeather.queryYahooWeatherByGPS(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mListener );

        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

    }
}
```

(note: Classes are generally uppercase, and better nouns -- "searchByGPS" sounds like a method, while "SearchByGPSTask" indicates that it's a class meant to do something.)

Comment: Now got this error: "Ca't create handler inside looper that has not called looper.prepare();"

Comment: That appears to be unrelated to your first question. Does the logcat point into your own code or inside yahoo's?

Comment: That problem is solved. Now it can't find textview inside fragment.

Answer (score 0):

With this line `mYahooWeather.queryYahooWeatherByGPS(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), (YahooWeatherInfoListener) this);`, you are trying to cast the `AsyncTask` to a `YahooWeatherInfoListener`. Use `HomeFragment.this` instead